# WebserviceHeader - Query

Tags: webservices

```
ABCDWebserviceHeader.MessageSource MessageSource = new ABCDWebserviceHeader.MessageSource();

    MessageSource.ApplicationName = 'ABCD';
    MessageSource.ApplicationUserID = 'QQQQQQ';
    MessageSource.HostName = 'local';
    MessageSource.ProcessID = '123456';
    MessageSource.UserID = 'JohnSmith';
    XYZHeader.MessageSource = MessageSource;
```

Can anyone please explain WebserviceHeader/MessageSource (IS IT A GENERIC THING? ) and what the above code is doing?
Searched for WebserviceHeader with not much information .

Answer (score 1):

This code is calling a class that was likely generated by WSDL2Apex. SOAP, an XML-based web service call protocol, allows you to have "headers" and a "body." The headers are **implementation-specific**. Consult the documentation for the service it calls to find out what the parameters are, and how they affect the service call. WebserviceHeader and MessageSource are simply the variable names that the developers used for creating the service. They could just as easily called them Header and Source, or any other words they wanted to, but chose to use those names. They are not "standard" in any real sense.